# Numpy take using multiple dimension indices

Tags: python, numpy

I need a general function `f(array, axis, indices)` to specify arbitrary axis in a numpy array. Here

- `array` is a numpy array of arbitrary number of dimensions
- `axis` is a tuple that specifies the dimensions of the array
- `indices` is a tuple that specifies the indices of the above axis

For example, if I have a 6 dimensional array `A`, the value of the function `f(A, (0,3,4), (20, 70, 3))`  would be

```
A[20, :, :, 70, 3, :]
```

I suspect that one can use [np.take](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) to achieve this the following way

```
def f_take(A, axis, indices):
    A1 = A.copy()

    # Make sure we iterate over axis in descending order
    descAxIdx = np.flip(np.argsort(axis))
    descAxis = np.array(axis)[descAxIdx]
    descIndices = np.array(indices)[descAxIdx]

    for ax, ind in zip(descAxis, descIndices):
        A1 = np.take(A1, ind, ax)
    return A1
```

Does this function already exist in `numpy`? I could use `f_take` I wrote, but speed is an issue for me, so if there is something purely compiled (no python loop), that would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be implemented simply as this:

```py
import numpy as np

def f(a, axes, indices):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    slices = tuple(indices[axes.index(i)] if i in axes else slice(None)
                   for i in range(a.ndim))
    return a[slices]
```